# Appium session times out using BitBar cloud before I have chance to do anything

Tags: timeout, appium, bitbar

I'm using the Appium GUI to try to connect with the cloud servers at BitBar.  I have entered the capabilities, including my API key and app id, and the connection starts successfully.  However, once the app loading screen comes up, the test stops due to the following error:

`Command timeout, no command received in last 0 seconds. Did you call webdriver quit()?`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to increase `newCommandTimeout` or remove that capability. It seems you set it to 0.

If you use Appium Desktop, it's [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/blob/v1.15.1/app/main/appium.js#L201), according to [appium changelog](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changes-in-version-0123-from-0122) Bitbar handles 0 value improperly. It's going to be fixed soon.

Comment: Do I put that command in the desired capabilities?  I haven't set any timeouts so far.  This is my desired capability list:

{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8.0",
  "bitbar_apiKey": "<MY API IS HERE>",
  "bitbar_device": "Google Pixel XL",
  "bitbar_app": "<APP ID HERE>",
  "bitbar_target": "android",
  "deviceName": "Android Phone",
  "automationName": "Appium"
}

Comment: I don't know, the default value is 60 when you don't set it. However, in logs I can see that 0 came from you. Maybe it's specific to the client/driver you use?

Comment: Maybe, it's certainly not something I set myself, but it's working now